# Hibernate constraint-mapping validator with message

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

Here is the validation.xml

```
<constraint-mappings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping validation-mapping-1.1.xsd"
                 xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping" version="1.1">
<default-package>com.esq.rbac.model</default-package>
<bean class="Tenant" ignore-annotations="true">
    ...
    <field name="ivrPin">
        <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Size">
            <element name="min">6</element>
            <element name="max">6</element>
            <message>IVR Pin must be 6 digit numeric</message>
        </constraint>
        <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Pattern">
            <element name="regexp">[0-9]+</element>
        </constraint>
    </field>
</bean>
```

During execution getting error saying

```
c.e.u.imports.Main [run] - HV000115: Error parsing mapping file.
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000115: Error parsing mapping file.
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 
Invalid content was found starting with element 'message'. One of '{"http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping":element}' is expected.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
```

How to include the error message properly

Comment: Specifying `message` before `element` tags, directly after `constraint annotation` will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make one change by placing your `message` directly after `constraint annotation` tag, before the `element` tags.

```
<bean class="Tenant" ignore-annotations="true">
...
<field name="ivrPin">
    <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Size">
        <message>IVR Pin must be 6 digit numeric</message>
        <element name="min">6</element>
        <element name="max">6</element>

    </constraint>
```

The reason for this is as follows:

If you look at the xsd file for validation-mapping:

**validation-mapping-1.1.xsd**

```
<xs:complexType name="constraintType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="message" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element type="map:groupsType"
                    name="groups"
                    minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element type="map:payloadType"
                    name="payload"
                    minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element type="map:elementType"
                    name="element"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded"
                    minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="annotation" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

It is using `xs:sequence` tag which specifies that the child elements must appear in a sequence. Refer [element sequence](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#element-sequence). Here *message* attribute comes before other attributes like *groups*, *payload* or *element*.

Comment: The explanation makes answer perfect